# Using two buttons (submit button and a normal button) which should submit the same form differently

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used jquery wizard plugin to create this form.
The form get submitted when I use the ID = "next" submit button.
when I use the ID = "quick" button it will redirect to the Feedback.Form but it will not submitted  properly. (I cant see the db has been updated properly.)

```
    $j("#quick").click(function(){
      $j('#feedbackForm').submit();
    });
```

---

`<form id="feedbackForm" method="post" action="<openmrs:contextPath/>/module/feedback/addFeedback.form" class="bbq" enctype="multipart/form-data" >`

---

```
<div id="bottomNavigation">
    <input id="back" value="Back" type="reset" />
    <input id="next" value="Next" type="submit" />
    <input id="quick" value="Just submit now with all the defaults!" type="button" />
</div>
```

Please can any one help me on this?

Thanks, 
Harsha

Full source : https://gist.github.com/3227043

Comment: Post what you've done here and what you think is wrong with it for people to fix it please!

Comment: When asking a question, please only post relevant code. Make a small example of what isn't working, not your entire page. Nobody wants to look through that.

Comment: hi Im sorry for that, hope now okay with that,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the "next" button to normal button and add and if or switch selection into the jquery code. So both buttons were normal and Jquery will decide which ones takes to submit getting the name of the button who calls the click event. Or you can do it trough a javascript function, well, you can do it in any way as you want, but both buttons must be "button" type